# Round Up Decimal Values in SSRS Report

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I cannot get to round up or fix the value of my outcome to Two or one decimal places in Report Builder.

I am using Code in my Report Builder Expression:

```
=SUM(Fields!COMPLETE.Value)/SUM(Fields!Total.Value)*100 & "%"
```

After the division i get results like `26.33333415%` or `37.4512654%`. How can I round this up to two decimals?

I tried to to do it from the Text Box Properties setting it to 0 or 1 decimals, didn't work.
Don't know how to round up with this.

Expected Results: `26.3% & 37.4%` Or `26.33% & 37.45%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `CEILING` or `FLOOR` functions to accomplish rounding.

```
=CEILING(SUM(Fields!COMPLETE.Value)/SUM(Fields!Total.Value)*100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the option MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero

```
Round(0.5, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```